Se borran datos de mi carpeta y genera problemas con un nuget
estoy actualizando una web y al guardarla o debuggear se borran los archivos de
...\bin\app.publish\bin\es,
lo que me genera un problema con un Nuget y dejan de funcionar o cargar ciertos scripts (o eso me dice el error de la consola en el navegador). No logro descifrar la razón que por qué pasa eso.
La solución hasta ahora es copiar esos archivos (.dll) desde la carpeta original a mi versión actualizada - tuve que bajar el proyecto original y copiar la carpeta del proyecto completa y trabajar sorbe esa copia.
Estoy usando visual studio 2022 en un proyecto .net
Entonces, me gustaría entender por qué pasa esto y si hay alguna solución más eficiente y mantenible.
Este es el error:
Gravedad    Código  Descripción Proyecto    Archivo Línea   Estado suprimido
Error       No se pudo restaurar el paquete de NuGet para el proyecto ProyectoBase.Web: No se puede encontrar una parte de la ruta de acceso '...\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.3.6.0\build/net45/Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.Extensions.targets'.. Vea la ventana Lista de errores para consultar los errores y las advertencias con más detalle.             

Soy nuevo en este mundo
